# jQuery add & remove textbox

Tags: jquery, text, input, addition

i have this set of html codes that i want to append another input="text" to increase the number of textbox as i click '+' but i am not sure of the parent().parent() function. Can anyone help?

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/2XJXu/) is my jquery and html extraction, sorry they do look abit messy because of absence of css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `.append()` would help you adding elements and `.remove()` removing 'em (see [example #1](http://jsfiddle.net/2XJXu/8/) and [example #2](http://jsfiddle.net/2XJXu/10/)).

So, `element.append(content);` adds `content` to the end of `element` HTML (before its closing tag). `element.remove();` removes `element` from wherever it was so you should use this for your 'minus' button with `$("your_tr > td > label :last")` selector (selects last of labels with inputs from `your_tr`).

Comment: hi, there your append() works but i need to keep my logic of ensuring there is at least 1 textbox and a maximum of 5 textboxes. My current code allows that but yours simply throw in the text inputs without considering my logic. Is there anyway you manipulate the parent().parent() to reach the input text?

Comment: use `.length` property on selector: `if ($("[name=moo] > td > label").length < 5) ...`. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/2XJXu/12/ .

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of amendments...

HTML:

```
<td colspan="2" id="tasklist">
    <label>
        <input type="text" value="Create a task for this iteration" size="75%" height="25px"/>
    </label>
</td>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#tasklist").append('<input type="text" value="Create a task for this iteration" />');
```

Additional Notes

- You have no text within your label. The idea of the label is that it can aid users by describing what needs to be entered into the text box. You can choose to hide it with CSS if you don't want a visible label - but you should still have one

  Enter a task name

Don't want to show it? Hide it with CSS:

```
label {
    display: none;
}
```

- Tables shouldn't be used for layout
- Try to move your HTML attributes into CSS

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried giving the parent and id and referring to it by that, you can also use clone to make a direct copy of an input tag, remember to change the id of the clone before you append it to the parent as that will also be cloned.